# Number of celery tasks executed at a given point of time

Tags: celery, django-celery, celery-task, celeryd, djcelery

I am trying to create a bunch of celery tasks asynchronously on the fly. Say there are 1000 tasks I start asynchronously and I have only one celeryd process running to execute tasks. How many threads will be created by celery to handle these tasks?

If there are multiple threads that celery starts automatically to process the task queue, how do I limit celery to execute only 100 threads at a given point of time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Its starts as many as you specify with the `CELERYD_OPTS` [concurrency](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/tutorials/daemonizing.html#example-configuration) parameter.
Which is also discussed [here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#concurrency).

Comment: So the concurrency in celeryd_opts specifies how many tasks are executed by each of the worker processes?

Comment: yes, as explained [here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/configuration.html#concurrency-settings)